# How to use Keras preprocessing layers with functional APIs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Following sequential model is equal to the model created using functional API in the second code snippet.

```py
model = Sequential([
    Dense(...),
    Dense(...),
    Dense(...),
])
```

```py
input = Input(...)
x = Dense(...)(x)
x = Dense(...)(x)
output = Dense(...)(x)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

But, how can I include preprocessing layers into the model using functional APIs? What would be the functional approach of following sequential model?

```py
model = Sequential([
    Resizing(224, 224),
    Dense(...),
    Dense(...),
    Dense(...),
])
```

Comment: It's exactly the same as for any other layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the input layer as the first step, apply the preprocessing layers to the input, and then continue building the rest of the model as usual.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Resizing
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# Define the input layer
input = Input(shape=(...))  # Specify the input shape

# Preprocessing layers
x = Resizing(224, 224)(input)

# Rest of the model
x = Dense(...)(x)
x = Dense(...)(x)
output = Dense(...)(x)

# Create the model
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

Comment: In the Sequential approach, I didn't have to mention the Input shape though?

Comment: Thats it, in the sequential flavor the input shape is automatically inferred from the shape of the data that passes through that layer.